# PHP echo json with only two category and multiple records

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi Guys need some help.

So I'm trying to echo a json array format like this:

```
{"ttype": [{ "id":"1", "type":"Order No.","code":"ORDNO" },
            {"id":"2", "type":"Orderline", "code":"ORDLINE"} ]

,"input":[{"id":"1","order":"Order No.", "limit":"5"},
{"id":"2","order":"Order No.", "limit":"5"},
{"id":"2", "order":"Order Line No.","limit":"10"}]}
```

So here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";
$que = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $keyword = $row['keyword'];
    $parameters = $row['parameters'];

    $json = array(
            'ttype'=>array(array(
                'id'=>$id,
                'type'=>'',
                'code'=>$keyword
                )),'input'=>array(array(
                        'id' =>$id,
                        'order'=>'',
                        'limit'=>20
                 ))
        );

    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Problem is here is what i'm getting:

```
 {"ttype":[{"id":"1","type":"","code":"ORDNO"}],"input":[{"id":"1","order":"","limit":20}]}{"ttype":    [{"id":"2","type":"","code":"ORDLINE"}],"input":    [{"id":"2","order":"","limit":20}]}
```

Any idea how to get the right format  given properly?
Thanks

Comment: You need to build your data structure and use `json_encode()` only once, after the loop.

Comment: Hi jeroen?i've tried to put the json_encode() after the loop but i'm only getting a single record which is the id 2 only like this: {"ttype":[{"id":"2","type":"","code":"ORDLINE"}],"input":[{"id":"2","order":"","limit":20}]}

Comment: try putting json_encode($json,true) after while

Comment: Still Same result

Comment: Each object is being echo out. This produces invalid JSON where you are defining multiple root elements. You need to store all the objects within an array and then echo out the result. This way you will be returning an array of objects.

Comment: Hi Sir jeff, i've already solved my prbolem but anyway thank you for your answer and expect that i will use this knowledge you gave to me in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have two variables on while loop, then make your variables json_encode with your structure accordingly. This is the way you can get your work done

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved my problem.

So here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";
$que = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $keyword = $row['keyword'];
    $parameters = $row['parameters'];


    $array1[] = array(
        'id'=>$id,
        'type'=>'',
        'code'=>$keyword
        );

    $array2[] = array(
            'id'=>$id,
            'order'=>'',
            'limit'=>20
        );
}

 $globalarray = array(
                    'ttype'=>$array1,
                    'input'=>$array2
    );

echo json_encode($globalarray);
```

I'm now getting this result:

```
{"ttype":[{"id":"1","type":"","code":"ORDNO"},    {"id":"2","type":"","code":"ORDLINE"}],"input":[{"id":"1","order":"","limit":20},{"id":"2","order":"","limit":20}]}
```

Thank you for your help!
Especially to Sir Waleed Ahmed.
I owe you,your answer has given me an idea to make this possible.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";
        $que = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $keyword = $row['keyword'];
            $parameters = $row['parameters'];

            $json[] = array(
                    'ttype'=>array(array(
                        'id'=>$id,
                        'type'=>'',
                        'code'=>$keyword
                        )),'input'=>array(array(
                                'id' =>$id,
                                'order'=>'',
                                'limit'=>20
                         ))
                );

        }
        echo json_encode($json);
```